# There are no sites in the config file on nitro add

Tags: craft3, composer, nitro

When i try nitro add command to they return "There are no sites in the config file" what should i do?

```
Unable to locate a webroot, setting to web.
Enter the webroot [web] web
Added tutorial.test to config file
Apply changes from config? [yes] yes
Mounting ~/Nitro/projects/tutorial to nitro-dev
Adding site tutorial.test to nitro-dev
Applied changes from /home/pedro/.nitro/nitro-dev.yaml                          
[sudo] senha para pedro: 
There are no sites in the config file.
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and share the contents of `/home/pedro/.nitro/nitro-dev.yaml`?

Answer (score 1):

It probably because nitro doesn't overwrite your host file. You may need to edit it yourself using nano (assuming you're on linux).

sudo nano /etc/hosts

you will need to provide

- the IP address- that you can find using `nitro info` in the terminal or by opening the nitro-dev shell in multipass
- the hostname- example.test or whatever else that may be

There is a github issue raised for it, see https://github.com/craftcms/nitro/issues/213